# ffmpeg setting ouput option correctly (-r)

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg on Ubuntu with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -vf scale=w=320:h=-1 -y -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 60 output_video
```

For the -r option the documentation says:

> -r[:stream_specifier] fps (input/output,per-stream)
>
> Set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation).
>
> As an input option, ignore any timestamps stored in the file and
>   instead generate timestamps assuming constant frame rate fps. This is
>   not the same as the -framerate option used for some input formats like
>   image2 or v4l2 (it used to be the same in older versions of FFmpeg).
>   If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.
>
> As an output option, duplicate or drop input frames to achieve
>   constant output frame rate fps.

I would like to use the output option. How can I do this? What is the per-stream option doing (it is not written above)?

Second, is it correct that the `-vf scale=w=320:h=-1` option scaled the video to width 320 and keeping the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use the `-r` output option. How can I do this?

Your command is using it as an output option. The location of options is important as it determines what is applied to the input or the output:

```
ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

> What is the per-stream option doing (it is not written above)?

"per-stream" means that this option can be declared several times to apply to different streams using [stream specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1). Since you have only one video stream in your output you can ignore this.

> Second, is it correct that the `-vf scale=w=320:h=-1` option scaled the video to width 320 and keeping the aspect ratio?

Yes, but when encoding with libx264 consider using `-2` instead of `-1`. It does the same thing but makes sure the result is divisible by 2 which is required for this encoder (there are exceptions).